# What is the right way to add a year to COledateTime taking into account leap years?

Tags: c++, mfc, coledatetime

I have this code:

```
COleDateTime datStart = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime(), datEnd;

// Update end date (one year later)
datEnd.SetDateTime(datStart.GetYear() + 1,
    datStart.GetMonth(),
    datStart.GetDay(),
    datStart.GetHour(),
    datStart.GetMinute(),
    datStart.GetSecond());
```

The above code failed yesterday (Feb 29, 2020) because `datEnd` resulted in **Feb 29, 2021** which is not valid.

What is the right way to safely add a year to `datStart` taking into account leap years?

C# has:

```
DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yearInTheFuture = theDate.AddYears(1);
```

What is the equivalent for MFC/C++?

One possibility is:

```
COleDateTimeSpan spnYear;
spnYear.SetDateTimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);

datEnd = datStart + spnYear;
```

But it is still potentially flawed due to leap years having 366 days. So what is the right way?

I see this similar question:

[C++ add 1 year to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450569/c-add-1-year-to-date)

It implies using `boost`. I do have boost in my project although never used it for date manipulation. Wonder if this can be used with a `COleDateTime` object?

Using `boost`:

```
boost::gregorian::date dStart{ datStart.GetYear(), datStart.GetMonth(), datStart.GetDay() };
boost::gregorian::date dEnd = dStart + boost::gregorian::years(1);

datEnd.SetDateTime(
    dEnd.year(),
    dEnd.month(),
    dEnd.day(),
    datStart.GetMonth(),
    datStart.GetMinute(),
    datStart.GetSecond());
```

Doesn't compile.

```
4>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\PublishersDatabaseDlg.cpp(354,49): error C2398: Element '1': conversion from 'int' to 'boost::gregorian::date::year_type' requires a narrowing conversion
4>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\PublishersDatabaseDlg.cpp(354,70): error C2398: Element '2': conversion from 'int' to 'boost::gregorian::date::month_type' requires a narrowing conversion
4>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\PublishersDatabaseDlg.cpp(354,89): error C2398: Element '3': conversion from 'int' to 'boost::gregorian::date::day_type' requires a narrowing conversion
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ add 1 year to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450569/c-add-1-year-to-date) In particular, pay attention to the answer that starts with "There is no such thing as "adding a year".".

Comment: What do you want the result to be? As for your errors you get when using boost: The compiler is complaining about a narrowing conversion. This is due to the use of brace initialization. Either explicitly cast the year/month/day values to an appropriate type, or use direct initialization with parentheses (`dStart( datStart.GetYear(), ... );`).

Comment: @IInspectable I have fixed that compilation error and now I have another: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-x64-1_71.lib'`. I can't see any lib files in the boost folder structure.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with boost, I'm afraid. The more important question still is: What is the result you expect when adding 1 year to any given time point? The implementation is (once that question has been answered), very likely trivial. And you don't need boost either, with C++' [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library.

Comment: @IInspectable I just want to add a year to the starting date. That is all. Yesterday I had introduced a leap year because because tweaking the literal year resulted in a bogus date 29-2-2021. I am happy to try `std::chrono`. Not used it before.

Comment: That's understood, but what is a year to you? Is it 365 days, always? 365 days by default, with 366 days when the range includes 29th of February? 365.25 days? 365.2425 days? Something else?

Comment: Fair point. I just wanted to avoid the crash. I have kept it simple and used the 365 day span.

Comment: See my [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60479748/boost-error-libboost-system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1-66-lib-c) about the boost lib. I had long ago moved to boost for dates. That @IInspectable says DATE is hideous is mild. :)

Comment: @lakeweb Thanks for the link. I am afraid that a lot of that is over my head. I am used to just downloading compiled libraries, ready to use with appropriate include headers. I will stick with my two lines of code. It does what I need. :)

Comment: @lak: You don't need boost. [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) has been part of C++ since C++11. With C++20, the library is finally completed, adding the missing pieces: calendars, timezones, parsing and formatting. The code in question would be as simple as this: `auto const datStart{chrono::system_clock::now()}; auto const datEnd{datStart + years{1}};` (in C++20), or `... +24h * 365` in C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`COleDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class) is a wrapper around the (hideously surprising) [`DATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/date-type) type. Internally it stores a 64-bit floating point value, where whole numbers represent the days since 30th of December, 1899 (midnight). The fractional part represents the time of day (e.g. `0.25` means 6 A.M., and `0.5` is noon). Every floating point value is a legal value and represents a unique<sup>1</sup> point in time.

Adding a year to a `COleDateTime` value amounts to adding the value `365.0` (or whichever value suits your needs) to its internal representation. This can be done by accessing the [`m_dt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class#m_dt) member directly

```cpp
COleDateTime datEnd{ datStart.m_dt + 365.0 };
```

or by using a [`COleDateTimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetimespan-class)

```cpp
datEnd = datStart + COleDateTimeSpan{ 365.0 };
// or
datEnd = datStart + COleDateTimeSpan{ 365, 0, 0, 0 };
```

This operation is always well defined, and will produce a valid time point regardless of leap years. Under the hood, it's just adding floating point values, that have no notion of calendrical properties. The following code

```cpp
COleDateTime datStart{ 2020, 2, 29, 0, 0, 0 };
COleDateTime datEnd{ datStart + COleDateTimeSpan{ 365.0 } };
```

will produce a time point that represents February 28th, 2021 (note that if you add `366.0` days, this will return March 1st, 2021).

---

The initial solution that attempts to construct a `COleDateTime` by doing arithmetic on the individual date components fails during construction. The constructor validates its input. When passed `(2021, 2, 29, 0, 0, 0)` it determines an invalid date, and sets [`m_status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class#getstatus) to `invalid`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *That's not entirely correct. Values in the range `(-1 .. 0]` map to the same time point as their absolute values. Note, that e.g. `COleDateTime{-0.25} == COleDateTime{0.25}` evaluates to `false`, even though they represent the same point in time.*