# COleDateTime::SetDateTime and noexcept (code analysis)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis, noexcept, coledatetime

See this code:

```
COleDateTime CSpecialEventDlg::GetSpecialEventDate() noexcept
{
    COleDateTime    datEvent;

    if (datEvent.SetDateTime(m_datEvent.GetYear(),
            m_datEvent.GetMonth(),
            m_datEvent.GetDay(),
            0, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        // Error

    }

    return datEvent;
}
```

My code analysis said I could add `noexcept` (which I did). But I decided to investigate a little more. I noticed that [`SetDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-160#setdatetime) returns a value:

> `Zero` if the value of this `COleDateTime` object was set successfully; otherwise, `1`. This return value is based on the `DateTimeStatus` enumerated type. For more information, see the [`SetStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-160#setstatus) member function.

For that latter function (`SetStatus`) it states:

> The *status* parameter value is defined by the `DateTimeStatus` enumerated type, which is defined within the *COleDateTime* class. See [`COleDateTime::GetStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-160#getstatus) for details.

Now, the documentation for `GetStatus` is documented to have a definition of:

> DateTimeStatus GetStatus() const throw();

So, it throws an exception if there is an error. Therefore, I decided to look at the MFC source for `SetDateTime`:

```
inline int COleDateTime::SetDateTime(
    _In_ int nYear,
    _In_ int nMonth,
    _In_ int nDay,
    _In_ int nHour,
    _In_ int nMin,
    _In_ int nSec) throw()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    ::ZeroMemory(&st, sizeof(SYSTEMTIME));

    st.wYear = WORD(nYear);
    st.wMonth = WORD(nMonth);
    st.wDay = WORD(nDay);
    st.wHour = WORD(nHour);
    st.wMinute = WORD(nMin);
    st.wSecond = WORD(nSec);

    m_status = ConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime(st) ? valid : invalid;
    return m_status;
}
```

It uses `ConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime` to set the status. *That* uses:

```
inline BOOL COleDateTime::ConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime(_In_ const SYSTEMTIME& systimeSrc)
{
    return AtlConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime(systimeSrc,&m_dt);
}
```

And *that* uses:

```
inline BOOL AtlConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime(
    _In_ const SYSTEMTIME& systimeSrc,
    _Out_ double* pVarDtTm)
{
    ATLENSURE(pVarDtTm!=NULL);
    //Convert using ::SystemTimeToVariantTime and store the result in pVarDtTm then
    //convert variant time back to system time and compare to original system time.
    BOOL ok = ::SystemTimeToVariantTime(const_cast<SYSTEMTIME*>(&systimeSrc), pVarDtTm);
    SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
    ::ZeroMemory(&sysTime, sizeof(SYSTEMTIME));

    ok = ok && ::VariantTimeToSystemTime(*pVarDtTm, &sysTime);
    ok = ok && (systimeSrc.wYear == sysTime.wYear &&
            systimeSrc.wMonth == sysTime.wMonth &&
            systimeSrc.wDay == sysTime.wDay &&
            systimeSrc.wHour == sysTime.wHour &&
            systimeSrc.wMinute == sysTime.wMinute &&
            systimeSrc.wSecond == sysTime.wSecond);

    return ok;
}
```

At this point I have got lost. In short, I am assuming that `SetDateTime` **does not** throw an exception.

---

I understand this much, if I decide to make a call to `GetStatus` inside the `if` clause then we do have a potential for exception to be thrown.

Comment: Rather than leave my original bunch of comments, I decided to amalgamate them into an answer. Not sure if it fully addresses your concerns, but it may go *some* way to clearing your doubts.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I gave up on using COleDateTime some time ago. It is still in some of my code, but I have a date class that can eat COleDateTime while I replace it. The biggy for me is that they use a double!!?? [Leap years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473361/what-is-the-right-way-to-add-a-year-to-coledatetime-taking-into-account-leap-yea)?? [the paste](https://pastebin.com/TevHYTeD) if you like. And you now have access to all the boost::gregorian goodies!

Comment: @lakeweb I have heavily used `COleDateTime` in my project over the years and have some bits fine tuned for languages like Polish and Maltese. So I am reluctant to change the class I use now. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three MFC functions for which you have shown the source code (`COleDateTime::SetDateTime`, `COleDateTime::ConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime` and `AtlConvertSystemTimeToVariantTime`) have – according to their declarations – the potential to throw exceptions (because they have no specification to the contrary, such as `noexcept`).

However, that doesn't mean that they will (or are even likely to). Digging a bit further into the MFC source code, the only place I can see, in those three functions, where an exception could be thrown is in the `ATLENSURE(pVarDtTm!=NULL);` line (in the third function).

The `ATLENSURE` macro is defined as follows:

```cpp
#define ATLENSURE(expr) ATLENSURE_THROW(expr, E_FAIL)
```

And `ATLENSURE_THROW` is, in turn, defined thus:

```cpp
#define ATLENSURE_THROW(expr, hr)          \
do {                                       \
    int __atl_condVal=!!(expr);            \
    ATLASSUME(__atl_condVal);              \
    if(!(__atl_condVal)) AtlThrow(hr);     \
} __pragma(warning(suppress:4127)) while (0)
```

So, it would seem that, in your code, an exception will be thrown if `expr` (in the above snippets) is null (the double-bang, `!!` pseudo-operator makes any non-zero value into `1` and leaves a zero as zero). That `expr` is the result of the `pVarDtTm!=NULL` expression, which can only be `0` (`false`) if the `&m_dt` argument in the call in your second MFC source excerpt is *itself* NULL – and, as the address of a member of the class object through which it is being called, that seems improbable (if not *impossible*).

---

Another issue you have is that you appear to misunderstand what the `throw()` specification in the `DateTimeStatus GetStatus() const throw();` declaration means. As [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exception-specifications-throw-cpp?view=msvc-160), it is actually (since C++17) an alias for `noexcept` (or `noexcept(true)`, to be more precise). To specify that a function can throw *any* type of exception, the `throw(...)` or `noexcept(false)` specifications should be used (or use no except/throw specification at all).

So, your last sentence is not really true:

> *I understand this much, if I decide to make a call to `GetStatus` inside the `if` clause then we do have a potential for exception to be
> thrown.*

Because the `GetStatus()` function is specified *explicitly* as non-throwing, and you *already* have a call to the `SetDateTime` member function, which (as described above) *can* throw an exception (but won't, in your code).

Comment: Thanks. So for my code I should remove the noexcept keyword then …? Sounds like it.

Comment: @Andrew Seems like it's safe to leave it, from how I understand the MFC source code and calling chain. Your code analyser appears to agree with me.

Comment: Leave it, as in, leave it in?

Comment: Yes. Use the `noexcept` specification. In the *extremely unlikely* event that an exception is raised during a call to that function, your program will call `std::terminate` (assuming a C++17 or later standard). Furthermore, unless *every* call you make to your `GetSpecialEventDate` function is enclosed in a `try...catch` block, then the program will crash and burn, anyway.